# Window open function works but immediately closes the newly opened window

Tags: angular, google-chrome, blob

I have a blob that is returned by the server. What I want to do is open the contents of a blob in a new tab.

I am currently creating a new file-url using that blob. Then I open it using window.open().

The code seems to be working and opens the window for a split second on Chrome.  Then it closes immediately. (I have enabled popup for the domain I am working on).

This is my code.

```
this._documentService.download(document.DocumentId).subscribe((data:any) => {
  let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);//data => blob
  window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
},
error => {
  console.log("Error downloading document", error);
});
```

However if I visit the url manually(by copying it from the source and pasting it in the address bar), the tab does not close immediately. It stays put and that is what I want.

I don't know why this is happening. Thanks.

Edit: seems to be working fine in incognito mode.

Comment: Is Chome saving it to the downloads?

Comment: @JoshLee. Yes it does. But in an incorrect format.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned that it works fine in incognito mode, I assume the reason is browser extension(s), such as ad blockers etc. Try to disable them one by one and you'll find the culprit.